# How do I build multiple jar files using scala sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

In my project I have the following structure:

> src/
>
> plugins/
>
> > \__ mpc
> >
> > |__ oper

I compile all of the scala files in src into a single jar (the main program), then each subdirectory in plugins contains scala files that should build a plugin jar to be loaded by the main program (so one jar for plugins/mpc and another for plugins/oper).

In the root I have a build.sbt:

> name := "mrtoms"
>
> organization := "chilon"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq("commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1")
>
> crossPaths := false
>
> scalaHome := Some(file("/usr/share/scala"))
>
> target := file("project/target")
>
> scalaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src")
>
> mainClass := Some("org.chilon.mrtoms.MrToms")

That builds my main jar file from the files in src just fine.. how do I add jars for the sources file in each plugin directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you need full configuration (at the moment you are using basic one):

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration

In your case, `root` project is your main jar. Each plugin should then have it's own project, that root project aggregates. Full configuration can be something like this:

```
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) aggregate (mpc, oper) 
    lazy val mpc  = Project("mpc", file("plugins/mpc")) dependsOn(pluginApi)
    lazy val oper = Project("sub2", file("plugins/oper")) dependsOn(pluginApi)
    lazy val pluginApi = Project("pluginApi", file("plugins/api"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :) In my case I added root.. which compiles nothing.. just to aggregate to subprojects. Then all of the subprojects depend on the plugin subproject from there. The root project builds an empty jar, and the scala compiler keeps giving an "out of memory" warning on the first compile ;) but other than that it's looking good.

Comment: Seems the documentation has moved (and hopefully gotten better) in the mean while. http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html or maybe this: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html